# How to implement blogging feature in umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog, umbraco7

Recently I am started exploring Umbraco 7 cms and building a site where I need to implement a blogging feature.I want to do it using MVC razor syntax but I am also open for extension.But primarily I want to do it using coding . Please help me by giving some ideas and resources to accomplish the task.

Thanks

Utpal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uDateFoldersy](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/udatefoldersy) for this purpose. using it you will be able to do following with out any coding.

> - Configure multiple nodeTypeAliases for landing (root eg. news, blog) nodes.
>
>   - Configure multiple nodeTypeAliases for nodes to put in date folders (eg. article, blogpost)
>   - Configurable property alias for date property (you can call it anything!)
>   - Automatic folder creation occurs on the Saved event.
>   - Change of a date in a node results in the node being moved.
>   - Moving a node to another date folder results in the date being changed.
>   - Year, month and day folders can be disabled
>   - Nodes can be created directly on a year or month folder, and will stay at the folder.
>   - Define your own date folders (if you want)
>   - The package includes mvc view and a master page.

This will make your development a lot easier as the basic features needed to implement for a standard blog will be done with this extension.

Answer (score 0):

A complete blog package is [UBlogsy](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/ublogsy), it has tags, categories, authors, data folders and more. Also working in Umbraco 7 (see details on downloadpage)

For a blogwebsite I created my own Razor scripts to run it the way I want it to Run ;)